# Order of column values gets changed after selecting a column from dataframe Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a requirement where I have to get the table name based on the entity name. For eg. if entity_nm is "QUOTE_HEADER" it should return table name "Q2CODS.QUOTE_HEADER_TSS" and if entity name is "QUOTE_LINE_ITEMS" it should return table name "Q2CODS.QUOTE_LINE_ITEM_TSS"

```
val srcentity_dstTable = dataFrame.select("ENTITY_NM", "DS_TABLE_NM")
srcentity_dstTable.show(200)
```

here is the dataframe that have two columns ENTITY_NM & DS_TABLE_NM

[image]

when I select ENTITY_NM column and convert it to a list, the values are not coming in the same order as the above Dataframe.

```
val srcentity_columns = srcentity_dstTable.select("ENTITY_NM").collect().map(_ (0)).toList
println(srcentity_columns)
val dst_table_names = srcentity_dstTable.select("DS_TABLE_NM").collect().map(_ (0)).toList
println(dst_table_names)
 val mapcols = (srcentity_columns zip dst_table_names)
println(mapcols)
```

Here the entity_nm list is not coming in the same order as dataframe, instead all the quote_headers are coming first and all the quote_line_items at the end

[image]

Please anyone let me know why this reordering happening for entity_nm only when ds_table_nm list is coming in order as in the DataFrame.

Comment: It is because the spark is distributed and there is no guarantee the select statements will give you the same order as you see in the show command. also if you want to select the ENTITY_NM, DS_TABLE_NM, and want to maintain the same key and value there is an alternative way instead of collecting those two fields individually.

Comment: oh okay.. got it.. Could u please tell me what is the alternative way to do it? Thanks for your Reply

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a new column and collect that new column.

For example:

```
val list =List(("one", "A"), ("two", "A"), ("three", "B"), ("one", "B")).toDF
        
val df = list.toDF("ENTITY_NM", "DS_TABLE_NM")
        
df.show()
        
        +---------+-----------+
        |ENTITY_NM|DS_TABLE_NM|
        +---------+-----------+
        |      one|          A|
        |      two|          A|
        |    three|          B|
        |      one|          B|
        +---------+-----------+
        
 val newDF = df.withColumn(
                "new_column",
                concat($"ENTITY_NM", lit("-"), $"DS_TABLE_NM")
              )

 newDF.show
        +---------+-----------+----------+
        |ENTITY_NM|DS_TABLE_NM|new_column|
        +---------+-----------+----------+
        |      one|          A|     one-A|
        |      two|          A|     two-A|
        |    three|          B|   three-B|
        |      one|          B|     one-B|
        +---------+-----------+----------+
```